# Extract a string in between two strings if a sub-string occurs in between those two strings- Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with two columns (time_stamp and message),as shown below:

**Example spark dataframe**

```
      message                                             time_stamp
irrelevant_text Startstring [ID: 1AB]                   2015-01-23 08:23:16
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:24:20
irrelevant_text mandatorystring ID [1AB]                2015-01-23 08:25:32
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:27:18
irrelevant_text endstring [ID: 1AB]                     2015-01-23 08:30:47
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:24:20
irrelevant_text Startstring [ID: 2BC]                   2015-01-23 10:05:16
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 10:24:20
irrelevant_text endstring [ID: 2BC]                     2015-01-23 10:30:47
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 10:50:20
irrelevant_text Startstring [ID: 3DE]                   2015-01-23 12:21:16
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 12:24:20
irrelevant_text mandatorystring ID [3DE]                2015-01-23 12:37:32
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 12:45:18
irrelevant_text endstring [ID: 3DE]                     2015-01-23 12:59:47
```

I am looking to extract the ID just after **Startstring** if **mandatorystring** exists between **Startstring** and **endstring** and discarding the IDs if mandatorystring **doesn't exists** between Startstring and endstring. There may be multiple such instances in one Date.

**Expected Output:**

```
time_stamp                    ID
2015-01-23 08:23:16          1AB
2015-01-23 12:21:16          3DE
```

Help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: third line seems different?  ID [1AB] instead of [ID: 1AB]

Comment: real data has a similar format. I tried to replicate the real data in the example dataset. But it is confirmed that whenever mandatorystring  will occur in between Startstring  and endstring, it will have same ID as Startstring  and endstring.

Answer (score 1):

Clean up the data using some regex and then use `lead` to check the requirements.

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'id',
    F.regexp_extract('message', 'ID[:|\s][\s|\[]([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\]', 1)
).filter('length(id) > 0').withColumn(
    'messagetype',
    F.when(F.col('message').rlike('Startstring'), 0).when(F.col('message').rlike('endstring'), 1).when(F.col('message').rlike('mandatorystring'), 2)
).drop('message').withColumn(
    'include',
    (F.col('messagetype') == 0) & (F.lead('messagetype').over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time_stamp')) == 2) & (F.lead('messagetype', 2).over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('time_stamp')) == 1)
).filter('include').select('time_stamp', 'id')

df2.show()
+-------------------+---+
|time_stamp         |id |
+-------------------+---+
|2015-01-23 08:23:16|1AB|
|2015-01-23 12:21:16|3DE|
+-------------------+---+
```

Comment: having some trouble here. The ID column is coming out to be blank.